# memory safety of volatile sig_atomic_t

Tags: c++, c, linux, signals

`volatile sig_atomic_t` is a guaranteed safe way of sharing data between a signal handler and the main application. What memory ordering guarantee does Posix make when running on a modern CPU with a more relaxed memory model. Specifically, should one use memory barriers / memory fences when reading or writing data using `volatile sig_atomic_t`?

Edit: Just to clarify. My question is how when using sig_atomic_t can we guarantee that bad things do not happen with regard to relaxed memory ordering especially in modern highly cached, multicore, etc architecture.

Comment: If you need to explicitly specify memory ordering, use C11 or C++11 atomic types.

Comment: I believe `sig_atomic_t` predates C++11, and that now you instead use C++11 atomics.

Comment: Also if I must use atomics, the volatile sig_atomic_t is never safe.

Comment: Anyways, C and C++ both have a `atomic_signal_fence()` function for coordinating non-atomic type (And atomic types requiring locking) order between a thread and a signal handler called on that thread. But if you stick with `volatile sig_atomic_t` variables that shouldn't be needed.

Comment: about volatile sig_atomic_t see section 21.1.3 of The Linux Programming Interface

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf except, C++11 atomics are not guaranteed to be lock free, and when they're not lock free, accessing them would not be safe within a signal handler.

Comment: @user2079303: "[mutex] would not be safe within a signal handler", why? Is that only a formal view, or is there any practical difference between being used from an asynchronous thread or from an asynchronous invocation of signal handler code? I somehow fail to see any difference, but there may possibly be a learning opportunity for me here. :)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Mainly formal view, as no guarantees are given, but also in practice: If the thread is holding the lock while the handler is invoked, the handler would be waiting for the lock until it is released. Unlike an asynchronous thread, which can move freely and eventually release the lock (barring multi-lock situations), the thread which has been interrupted won't move until the signal handler returns. Your thread ends up dead-locked by itself. I guess you might avoid this by blocking all signals when accessing the atomic variable, but I don't think that's very practical.

Answer (score 0):

POSIX does not make any memory ordering guarantees at present because it has not been integrated with the C++ (C11) memory model.

C11 ensures that objects of type `volatile sig_atomic_t` retain their values across signal handlers even without fences.  Other objects have indeterminate values if accessed.  `atomic_signal_fence` is mis-named because as specified in the standard, it cannot be used to access objects of other types (besides `volatile sig_atomic_t`) in such a way that they retain their values across signal handlers.

For asynchronous signals, it is possible to avoid these issues by handling them in a dedicated thread and blocking them for all other threads.  For most synchronous signals (such as `SIGFPE` triggered by integer division by zero, or `SIGBUS` or `SIGSEGV` for access to unmapped memory), I do not think any of the standards specify what happens.  This is really odd because *asynchronous* signals should be harder to tackle, but currently, the reverse is true.